# Apply jquery rotation animation on fixed axis directly on image to simulate swinging effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-transforms

I have certain images in my website which are positioned absolutely within a parent container and since the site is responsively working as i need, i would not like to include the images inside fixed width div or anything. These images are basically objects attached to a string which i have positioned as if they are hanging to the page.
Now i am trying to animate them in a way so as to create a pendulum like swinging effect - as if they are hanging on a thread. I have seen some articles on similar effects and [this one](http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/jquery-pendulum-animation-pivot-point/) seems most promising, but i am unable to apply it maybe because it requires the image to be in a div. 
[Here is the jsbin](http://jsbin.com/leme/1/edit?html,css,js,output) for what i am trying. I am gonna start with applying rotation directly to images and then proceed to create the proper animation. unfortunately i am stuck at the very first step.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to set *position* to relative

```
#plane {
    margin-left:100px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
}
```

position static (the default) is not *transformable*